# Program in Python that converts sorted string array based on repeated elements

Tags: python

First time writing here, sorry if unclear explanation. I have sorted array from input strings called t which I sorted alphabetically, then I want to make another array called new which counts numbers of repeated elements for example `['a','a','b','c','s','s','s']` should be `['2','1','1','3']`. The way I did it does not count in the last element (it would be `['2','1','1']`. Please help

```py
s = input("Enter words: ").split(" ")

length = len(s)
t = [None] * length
for i in range(length):
    t[i] = s[i]

    #then did some code to sort array t, guess it's not so relevant to show here

    repeatedcount = 1

    j = 0

    new = [None] * length
    for i in range(1,length):
        if (t[i] == t[i-1]): #does not count the last time it repeats
            repeatedcount+=1
        else:
            new[j] = repeatedcount
            j += 1
            repeatedcount = 1
```

Comment: I edited your question so it uses code blocks, but there is still some issue with the example code. You didn't showed indents which are crucial for python code to follow the scope. Try to show us the working solution of the code

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I did put them in Python, but still having trouble getting used to formatting on this website. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Don't be sorry everyone of us was a starter. I generally use VSC for python and copy directly from it, which works fine. Which editor do you use?

Comment: I use PyCharm sir

Answer (score 2):

use the Counter object from pythons standard library "collections"

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b']
print(Counter(mylist))
>> Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1})
```

[detailed examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Comment: Why is the exampled updated in May 2020 and still showing Python2.X Code?

Comment: update: got it to work, used sorted_t = OrderedDict(sorted(t.items(), key=itemgetter(1))) to sort the items by frequency. Thanks again sir, so useful and kind!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use dict.

```
counter = {}
for char in a:
    if char not in counter.keys():
        counter[char] = 1
    else:
        counter[char] += 1

print(counter.values())
```